# StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation

Tags: java, api, android-studio, sdk

I have multiple StrictMode policy violation on my Android Studio app. I actually got these when trying to pre-launch my app on the Play Store. I don't think I got these warning when testing my app on my emulator device. I am not really sure what these are and where it came from. Here are all the stacktrace (shown below). Would really appreciate for any help even just handling one of the policy violation. Thank you!

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setCurveName(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECGroupContext.getECParameterSpec(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):7)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECPublicKey.getParams(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkKeyLength(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:84)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkCert(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:70)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.check(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:61)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:690)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:560)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:208)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:404)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Gd.A01(:34740)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Gd.A0K(:34919)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Gj.A00(:35248)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Gj.doInBackground(:35269)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.jav

StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setCurveName(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECGroupContext.getECParameterSpec(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):7)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECPublicKey.getParams(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkKeyLength(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:84)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkCert(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:70)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.check(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:61)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:690)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:560)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):5)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):6)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):16)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Gd.A01(:34740)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Gd.A02(:34794)

StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setCurveName(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECGroupContext.getECParameterSpec(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):7)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECPublicKey.getParams(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkKeyLength(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:84)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkCert(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:70)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.check(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:61)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:690)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:560)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):5)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):6)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):16)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Gd.A01(:34740)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Gd.A0K(:34919)

StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setCurveName(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECGroupContext.getECParameterSpec(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):7)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECPublicKey.getParams(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkKeyLength(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:84)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkCert(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:70)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.check(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:61)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:690)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:560)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):5)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):6)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):16)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnec

StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setCurveName(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECGroupContext.getECParameterSpec(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):7)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECPublicKey.getParams(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkKeyLength(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:84)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkCert(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:70)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.check(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:61)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:690)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:560)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):5)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):6)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):16)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)


StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setCurveName(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECGroupContext.getECParameterSpec(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):7)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECPublicKey.getParams(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkKeyLength(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:84)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.checkCert(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:70)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ChainStrengthAnalyzer.check(ChainStrengthAnalyzer.java:61)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:690)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:560)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):5)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):6)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):16)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLCo

StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setCurveName(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECGroupContext.getECParameterSpec(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):7)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECPublicKey.getParams(:com.google.android.gms@210214028@21.02.14 (100400-352619232):0)
    at sun.security.util.KeyUtil.getKeySize(KeyUtil.java:82)
    at sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$KeySizeConstraint.permitsImpl(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:551)
    at sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$KeySizeConstraint.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:518)
    at sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$Constraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:369)
    at sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.checkConstraints(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:215)
    at sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:140)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.check(AlgorithmChecker.java:261)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:301)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:703)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:560)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:208)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:404)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest
```

Comment: Hello, did you found a solution to this?